# Using existing Java code with React Native

Tags: java, android, react-native

I'm pretty new to React Native and mobile development in general. But I have a simple Java library with junit tests and I want to do one of two things:

1) I want to convert this Java code to be used naturally with React Native for development on iOS and Android.

2) I want to use this java code to be used only with Android in a native-hybrid application.

I probably have a few gaps in my understanding of how all this works. I understand that Java is native for Android, and therefore is only used for Android development. React native bridges the cross-platform gap to decompile react native code into platform specific code.

If I wanted to use my Java code for development on iOS, does that happen through [Native Modules](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-setup)? Is it possible to do regardless?

If it is only to be used on Android (which is fine), is using the setup described in the Native Modules section on React Native's website the way to go?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot use your Java code under iOS. The "native" part of React Native is whatever is *native to the platform*, e.g., Java/Kotlin/whatever on Android, ObjC/Swift/whatever on iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, You cannot directly deploy code written by java to both Android and IOS in react-native. You can do it only for Android specific parts in react-native. If you want to use it as IOS compatible, you need to write a native module from IOS natives.

If u want to deploy your native Android module you can follow this https://hackernoon.com/first-experiences-with-react-native-bridging-an-android-native-module-for-app-authentication-501fec247b2b detailed example

If u want to create both android and IOS native modules u can follow this https://medium.com/@FizzyInTheHall/writing-a-react-native-bridge-library-bce5b90ea6d0 example